# Connect an existing user account twitter permanently

Tags: php, twitter

I want to be able to connect an existing user account to his twitter account.

I want to give the option for the user to connect his twitter account. After that is done once, I would like to be able to auto-tweet to his account.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

When the user logs in using their twitter credentials you retain an oAuth token that will allow you to call twitter APIs with the permissions the user granted when the token was generated.

This token can be revoked by the user at any time.

The twitter site has loads of great documentation on this area:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens